# Including a static content using RequestDispatcher from JSP is not working on GAE Java SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have a web-app running on the App Engine Java SDK 1.7.2. The app has no filter and no servlets besides the defaults for serving static content and JSP.

In a JSP file, I have a single line with something like:

```
<% request.getRequestDispatcher( "a.html" ).include( request, response ); %>
```

This is throwing a java.lang.IllegalStateException: "getOutputStream has already been called".

If I change the "a.html" for a dynamic content like "a.jsp", everything works fine. The documentation says a RequestDispatcher should work for dynamic and static content.

**OBS:** I am still learning Servlets and everything related, but I know there are other ways to achieve what I am doing here - this is just an example, not a real world scenario. I just would like to know if this is the expected behaviour and why. Or is it just a bug?

Comment: Wow! You are right. I confirmed it on my dev system. I think it is a bug. Hopefully someone from GAE can shed some light on this.

Comment: I did some more testing. This is not due to GAE. I got the same exception in a stand alone Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling, I learned that this bug has been around for a long time. Look at 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/165116/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/RequestDispatcher-include-throws-IllegalStateException
Strange as it might seem, the following works.

```
<%@page buffer="none"%>
<%
   request.getRequestDispatcher("a.html").include(request,response);
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for the further investigation you have done. I am also inclined to believe that this is really a bug. I have filed an issue report here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8266.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth you are putting scriplets in JSP, it is a horrible way of making your JSP's maintenance nightmare. Anyways looks like your request is already being sent before you are calling this method.

Comment: This is not a real app, I am not concerned about good design principles in this question, but I appreciate your reinforcement :) Regarding the response already being sent - This is a 1 line JSP and even in that case, I am not sure it should behave differently when including "a.jsp", instead of "a.html".